# Load multiple files through SQL Loader

Tags: unix, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have a requirement to load multiple files  received from two source systems into 1 table using SQL Loader.
To make this possible, I want to understand the following --

1. Pros and Cons of integrating multiple files like this ? - Need this to compare the merging option at source or via SQL Loader
2. Any other way of interfacing the data from .CSV files except SQL Loader in Oracle for multiple files  ? -- I don't think so but still need expert's confirmation
3. What are the things I need to mindful about?  -
   Ex-   file format and the header sequence should be same for all the files.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "Pros and cons" would require something to compare against.  It isn't obvious what you mean by "merging option at source".  I'd start with a host of questions like is this a nightly process where you get two total files a day?  What happens if you get a file from one source but not another?  What happens if one file has errors but not the other?  Are the files delivered to the database server (or a file system accessible to the database server)?  If so, my bias would be to prefer external tables to `SQL*Loader` but they're basically the same thing under the covers.

Comment: Thanks Justin. In event of file missing from the either sources, the process can proceed with just one file. In event of errors, process should stop . Files are delivered to a server different than the database server.

Comment: I am still looking out for various options but could you please share the steps to merge files via SQL Loader  or direct me to a Google page(listing the steps )